# How to inject a compiled Stylus bundle into html file using HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, webpack, stylus, html-webpack-plugin

I need to inject a Stylus bundle into the html file in webpack config file.

I already inject the js bundle using HtmlWebpackPlugin and I thought that it was possible to inject a compiled stylus bundle using this plugin too.

Below is my current `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfigForJS = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfigForStyles = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.styl',
    inject: 'head'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    cache: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfigForJS,
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfigForStyles
    ],
    stylus: {
        use: [require('nib')(), require('rupture')()],
        import: ['~nib/lib/nib/index.styl', '~rupture/rupture/index.styl']
    }
}
```

The only way I got the styles work was to add `require('./index.styl);` in my javascript file, but this is not what I need.

`HtmlWebpackPluginConfigForJS` works fine and successfuly injects the `index_bundle.js` file in my `index.html`. But it doesn't work with the styles.

---

Could you please help me to improve my webpack config to make it inject my stylus bundle correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default HtmlWebpackPlugin injects `css` files, from the docs:

> If you have any css assets in webpack's output (for example, css extracted with the ExtractTextPlugin) then these will be included with  tags in the HTML head.

So you can use [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to extract all your styles into one or several files. But to extract you should require your `index.styl` in your main `index.js` so that loader could see and make extraction.